# VirtualBox 'Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)'

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

VirtualBox wont let me start even though i downloaded every files that you need. It keeps saying something is wrong with the file /dev/vboxdrv but the file doesn't even exist

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you run elementary as a VirtualBox guest or are you running VirtualBox on elementary?

Comment: I have the same issue. I can install VirtualBox and start the Virtualbox Manager. I can create a virtualmachine (I created an Ubuntu VM with 50Gb drive and 4Gb memory). When I try to start the VM I get this message:
The virtual machine 'Ubuntu' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1). Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {85cd948e-a71f-4289-281e-0ca7ad48cd89}
. I also get the following window: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFsKc.png

Comment: Same Error. I've tryed to install Virtualbox from App Center and from APT and both gave the same error.